# Reading the JSON data

Tags: jquery, json, spring-mvc

I am trying to send some data from the controller to the view in Spring MVC using JSON, here is the code in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/twitter/searchgeomap", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String TwitterSearchGeoJSON(@RequestParam("query") String query) throws TwitterException {
    List<Status> tweets = twitterService.twitterSearchGeo(query);
    List<String> geoList = new ArrayList<String>();
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    for (Status tweet : tweets) {
        GeoLocation geo = tweet.getGeoLocation();
        String Latitude = String.valueOf(geo.getLatitude());
        String longitude = String.valueOf(geo.getLongitude());
        String text = tweet.getText();
        String place = tweet.getPlace().toString();

        geoList.add(text);
        geoList.add(Latitude);
        geoList.add(longitude);
        geoList.add(place);

        String key = String.valueOf(tweet.getId());
        json.accumulate(key, geoList);
    }

    return json.toString();
}
```

and here is how I am read the JSON in view:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $.getJSON("searchgeomap?query=obama", function(data){

            console.log("hi");
        });

});
```

The first question is that how can I set the parameter (query) so I wont need to put it into the request "searchgeomap?query=obama"? And the other problem is that `console.log("hi");` does not work and I cannot see the output in the console, why nothing is inside the function gets executed? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The function only gets executed if you have a successful response from the server (e.g. a 200 response).  Did you check that `yoursite.com/searchgeomap?query=obama` is accessible and responds with a 200 response?

Comment: It seems to work quite well in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P8KPR/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing @ResponseBody annotation in your controller signature, like this

```
public @ResponseBody String TwitterSearchGeoJSON(@RequestParam("query") String query) throws TwitterException
```

Answer (score 1):

well for the first question .. you can provide the data as object

```
$.getJSON("searchgeomap",{query:"obama"}, function(data){
        //--^^url--------^^---object

        console.log("hi");
 });
```

and for your second question.. does the url you are using here is in same domain.. looks like you are calling the twitter function.. anyways if it is then you need to look at ajax jsonp or else it won't work

Comment: Yes I am using the twitter API, but my request is on my localhost and it is not cross-domain. In fact in my controller, I get the data (search results) from Twitter API and then format them and send them as json...

Comment: check you developers tools console tab in chrome...if everything is fine... you should get the json returned by the controller there or else check your  reponse tab under network for that link you should have the return json object...